# Are returns predictable, Campbell and Shiller (1988)

Tags: asset-pricing, prediction

Following from the thread,

[Drivers of equity returns: dividend yield, change in P/E and dividend (or earnings) growth](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22298/drivers-of-equity-returns-dividend-yield-change-in-p-e-and-dividend-or-earnin/22318#22318)

1) Why are returns predictable from this, is there a reason?

2) Can we expect predictability in financial markets?

Comment: Related question: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34920/cochrane-on-return-predictability

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me start with a simple example. Suppose you have a dividend strip that pays an unknown dividend $D_T$. The gross return (something like 1.05 and NOT 5%!) on this security is, by definition, $$R_{t\to T} = \frac{D_T}{P_t}$$ where $P_t$ is the current price of this security. If we use lowercase letters to denote logs (i.e., $\log D_T = d_T$ etc..) we can rewrite the previous relationship as
$$p_t = d_T - r_{t \to T} \tag{1}\label{eq:1}$$
If we have a time series of log prices, returns and dividends we can take variances of both sides to obtain
$$Var(p_T) = Cov(p_T, d_T - r_{t \to T}) = Cov(p_T, d_T) - Cov(p_t,r_{t \to T})$$
Finally we can divide both sides by $Var(p_T)$ to obtain
$$1 = \frac{Cov(p_T, d_T)}{Var(p_T)} - \frac{Cov(p_t,r_{t \to T})}{Var(p_T)} = \beta_D - \beta_R \tag{2}\label{eq:2}$$
where $\beta_D$ $\beta_R$ are the slope coefficients you can obtain by running the following predictive time-series regressions
$$d_{T} = \alpha + \beta_D p_t + \epsilon_T$$
$$r_{t\to T} = \alpha + \beta_R p_t + \epsilon_T$$

Notice that \eqref{eq:2} tells you something very important: the price of the dividend strip predicts either dividends ($\beta_D \neq 0$) or returns ($\beta_R \neq 0$) or a combination of both! You can see that, in the case of a dividend strip, you should expect to be able to predict either dividends or returns.

A stock is nothing more than a collection of dividend strips and following the steps in [Drivers of equity returns: dividend yield, change in P/E and dividend (or earnings) growth](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22298/drivers-of-equity-returns-dividend-yield-change-in-p-e-and-dividend-or-earnin/22318#22318) you can have an approximation that is analogous to \eqref{eq:1}, i.e. :

$$pd_t = \sum \rho^j \Delta d_{t+j+1} - \sum \rho^j r_{t+j+1} \tag{3}\label{eq:3}$$

where $pd_t = \log \frac{P_t}{D_t}$, $\Delta d_{t+j+1} = \log \frac{D_{t+j+1}}{D_{t+j}}$ and $r_{t+j+1} = \log R_{t+j \to t+j+1}$. Similarly to before, you can take the variance of the log price-dividend ratio in \eqref{eq:3} to obtain
$$ 1 = \frac{Cov(pd_t,\sum \rho^j \Delta d_{t+j+1})}{Var(pd_t)} - \frac{Cov(pd_t,\sum \rho^j r_{t+j+1})}{Var(pd_t)}$$

As before, we can say that the price-dividen ratio $pd_t$ must either predict future realized dividend growth ($\sum \rho^j \Delta d_{t+j+1}$) or future log returns ($\sum \rho^j r_{t+j+1}$) or a combination of the two.

Coming back to your question 2) **if the price dividend ratio is not constant we should expect mechanically to have predictability or return, dividends or both**.

Empirically, price-dividend ratios are not constant and they seem to predict [mostly future returns](https://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/john.cochrane/research/papers/cochrane%20dog%20that%20did%20not%20bark.pdf), even though the evidence is [not as straightforward as it seemed at first](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2010.01575.x).